# Instant insanity(4 cubes puzzle) algorithm

Tags: algorithm, puzzle, graph-algorithm

I am trying to find an algorithm to solve the instant insanity puzzle. Here is the wiki link for the problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_Insanity

From wikipedia I found a graph theory algorithm to solve the puzzle. Another solution is brute force method of trying all possibilities. I am not sure how complicated it will be to code using graph theory algorithm. I have to complete the coding within a day. It will helpful if anyone can tell a better way to approach this.

Comment: In a paper Knuth discusses backtracking of the instant insanity problem to demonstrate some ideas about [Estimating the Efficiency of Backtrack Programs](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1975-29-129/S0025-5718-1975-0373371-6/S0025-5718-1975-0373371-6.pdf) . But maybe this is too complicate for a quick implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention the brute force solution, does that mean that it is an acceptable solution?  Or do you really need to come up with an algorithm?

A brute force approach only requires ~30K trials, so that means that your program will finish a few seconds after you write it ;-)

A brute force algorithm outline might look like:

```
for o1 in OrientationOptions {
 for o2 in OrientationOptions {
  for o3 in OrientationOptions {
   for o4 in OrientationOptions {
    if (isValidChoice (c1.o1, c2.o2, c3.o3, c4.4o)) {
     outputChoice();
     return;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was thinking on similar lines. I am not sure if I can use Brute force algorithm or I need to come up with algorithm. Another way I am thinking is by using graphs. Probably I need to ask for more details like if I can give Brute force solution.

Comment: Yeah, this is a good problem - I wasn't aware of it earlier, but now I have been thinking about it a bit.  Looking forward to your code and findings.

Comment: I managed to get the Brute force code working. It was not that difficult. But having hard time writing the code using graph algorithm. It is pretty complicated. It involves finding Euler paths in a multigraph. I am not so much confident on coding this. I will probably stick on the Brute force solution for now.

Comment: There may be only 41,472 unique block arangements, however, your brute force
algorithm may generate closer to 10 times that number of candidate solutions. `OrientationOptions` function gives 6 sides * 4 rotations per side = 24 options (brute force calculation since the actual number of unique rotations may be fewer due to having only 4
colours on the 6 sides of the cube). Then there are 4 nested loops each iterating over 
the 24 options giving 24**4 = 331,776
"solutions" to test. But in the end the program terminates upon finding the "first" solution
so will never complete the full iteration.

Comment: @CRS: it is not an [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)  but a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path).